# No package Az found

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

```
$ Get-InstalledModule -Name Az -AllVersions

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
0.5.0      Az                                  PSGallery            Azure Resource Manager Module. Cmdlets to manage...
```

Above block shows that Az is installed.. But following block says otherwise:

```
$ Update-Module -Name Az
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Az'. Try
Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2089 char:20
+ ...           $sid = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Comment: what does this have to do with azure cli? as for the powershell, i'd suggest manually removing this outdated module and installing a fresh one

Comment: Az is NOT outdated module. AzureRM was outdated.. Also, yes it is related to Azure-cli

Comment: 0.5.0 is outdated, 1.7.0 is the latest version. how is this related to azure-cli? its not connected to powershell in any way shape or form

Comment: If you would see my second command; that is what I was trying to do update-module Az ; but its throwing exceptions.. Thanks for looking into it..

Comment: azure cli != azure powershell, you know?

Comment: I think the confusion here is that Azure PowerShell now has a cross-platform module named `Az`. The name is similar enough to the CLI tool called `az` that these two are being confused within the clarification comments.

Comment: What is your PowerShell version ? `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: My PS Version is 5.1.16299.1004

Comment: This post resolved this issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696968/607701

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for help to everyone in comments... Here the main problem was the repository itself.. De-registering and registering it back solved the issue.

```
> Register-PSRepository -Default
```

Answer (score 1):

Using TLS1.2 connection solved the issue. Try executing below command before installing module Az-

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 

Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following ways are not in effect.

- [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
- Register-PSRepository -Default

I resolved by installing newer version of AzureRM.

PS> Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber