# PowerShell Installing NuGet, says unable to access internet, but I actually can

Tags: powershell, nuget

I followed the steps mentioned in [Using PowerShell Behind a Proxy](http://woshub.com/using-powershell-behind-a-proxy/) to configure my proxy server.

```
netsh winhttp set proxy "[IP]:[Port]"
$Wcl = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Creds = Get-Credential
$Wcl.Proxy.Credentials = $Creds
```

A dialog popped up to collect my credential on the third line.

Then I tried to install NuGet:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/
         ?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet
         connection.
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria
for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and
'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
```

The error message seems to indicate my PowerShell cannot connect to internet, but when I tried this command:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-WebRequest "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409"

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
                    &lt;SoftwareIdentity xmlns="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19770/-2/2015/schema.xsd"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:discovery="http://p...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-MD5: 01uMBNqAHedJsS1dqKC5oA==
                    Vary: Accept-Encoding
                    X-Cache: HIT
                    x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
                    x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
                    x-ms-request-id: 1b7af5a7-901e-0003-5d94-f5cc950000...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Content-MD5, 01uMBNqAHedJsS1dqKC5oA==], [Vary, Accept-Encoding], [X-Cache, HIT],
                    [x-ms-blob-type, BlockBlob]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : System.__ComObject
RawContentLength  : 1847
```

It seems it can connect to the Internet after all.

What did I do wrong? How do I install NuGet?

EDIT: 
I tried Ocaso Protal's suggestion:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force -proxy [ProxyServer:Port] -proxycredential $Creds
WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package
provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-Pac
   kageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackagePro
   vider

PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Creds

UserName                                   Password
--------                                   --------
[My UserName] System.Security.SecureString
```

It seems to have no effect.

Comment: Did you try the `-proxy` and `-proxycredential` parameter for [Install-PackageProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-packageprovider?view=powershell-6)? Ohh, and did you start Powershell as an admin?

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: Updated in edit. It seems to have no effect.

Comment: @OcasoProtal: Also yes I started PowerShell as admin.

Comment: I retried the Install-PackageProvider command with -verbose... the first time the message indicated it retried 3 times and cannot download the Microsoft URL. Then I tried again... and it succeeded. I have no idea why and it leaves a really bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: Hmmm, weird... Looks like there was maybe a problem on the Microsoft side?

Comment: @OcasoProtal I tried accessing the Microsoft URL in browser while I was having issues. The URL could be loaded successfully, it was a XML file containing URLs.

Comment: Still weird ;) But fortunately you got your problem solved

Answer (score 226):

could be TLS security related (ref: https://rnelson0.com/2018/05/17/powershell-in-a-post-tls1-1-world/)

Try this command first:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

then try to do the update. 
Note: the command only affects the current session and does not persist.

You may also check what version of TLS for client is set on computer. Looks like TLS 1.0 for client is required. (ref: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/wmf-5-1-upgrade-broken-repositories/)

Michael

Comment: We have just had this problem and it was the TLS fix above that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This worked , just resolved my on a Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: if your getting this in a docker build, look at answer below with registry changes.

Comment: I'm very late to the party, but I wanted to let you know that this command solved my issue on Windows Server 2016, PowerShell v5.1! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 24):

As per https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2265662-powershell-get-download-problem

I had the same problem today...

My issue was PowerShell Gallery would not download anything on W2016 boxes:

```bsh
VERBOSE: InstallPackage' - name='AzureRM.BootStrapper',
version='0.5.0',destination='C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\1254134668'
VERBOSE: DownloadPackage' - name='AzureRM.BootStrapper',
version='0.5.0',destination='C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\1254134668\AzureRM.BootStrapper\AzureRM.BootSt
rapper.nupkg', uri='https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.5.0'
VERBOSE: Downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.5.0'.
VERBOSE: An error occurred while sending the request.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.5.0' for '2' more
times
VERBOSE: An error occurred while sending the request.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.5.0' for '1' more
times
VERBOSE: An error occurred while sending the request.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.5.0' for '0' more
times
VERBOSE: Downloading package 'AzureRM.BootStrapper' failed, please make sure
'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.5.0' is accessable.
WARNING: Source Location 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/AzureRM.BootStrapper/0.5.0' is not valid.
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Package 'AzureRM.BootStrapper' failed to download.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1772 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Users\Admini...tStrapper.nupkg:String) [Install-Package], Excep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PackageFailedInstallOrDownload,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPac
   kage
```

What helped me to find out it was TLS v1.2 was this error in Fiddler:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception
```

From there I got this -> [A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception - The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925505/a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exception-the-local-security-authority-cannot)

Then tested locally with:

```bsh
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Which worked fine!

Hopefully, that will help somebody in the future :-)

You can set it for the whole .NET framework by editing registry:

```bsh
# Set strong cryptography on 64 bit .Net Framework (version 4 and above)
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord


# Set strong cryptography on 32 bit .Net Framework (version 4 and above)
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

This happened a few days ago on Windows Server 2016 Datacentre boxes, Win 2019 works fine still.

Commands thanks to:
https://johnlouros.com/blog/enabling-strong-cryptography-for-all-dot-net-applications

Happy Azure Stacking!!!

Comment: Thank you. We had Octopus Deploy tentacles running powershell on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter and powershell was complaining that a NuGet source was not valid. I ran the two commands to update the security for the .NET framework and everything is back to normal.

Comment: This is now mentioned at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-gallery-tls-support/

Comment: [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol += [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 adds tls12 to existing sec protocols instead of overridding. works good too

Comment: Thanks, those reg' edits fixed my issue with docker container builds... priceless...

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```

If the above doesn't work try this:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Answer (score 0):

Having taken many steps to overcome the similar problem, I just wanted to document the process in a more clear way. Here are the steps to overcome problems of NuGet and Docker installation in Windows Server (tested in 2016):

1. Make sure that Powershell version is 5.1 or higher:
   Get-Host | Select-Object Version
2. Update SSL/TLS versions supported by the server:

x64: Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord

x32: Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord

3. Restart the Powershell and check whether the desired effect is achieved:
   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol

(You should now see semeting like this:)
Tls, Tls11, Tls12, etc.

4. Install NuGet:
   Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
5. Install Docker:
   Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force
   Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force

Comment: HAve done ALL of this and still getting the failure to download.

Comment: If your work environment imposes a network wide proxy on your computer, this can help:

    Install-Module AzureDevOps -proxy "http://127.0.0.1:9000/localproxy-1709309785.pac"

substituting, of course, the URL of your local proxy. The local proxy pac URL can be viewed in the UI in Settings > Network and Internet Settings > Proxy, or you may find it with one of the answers to https://serverfault.com/q/696020/190386.   For myself, the only Powershell answer that worked was https://serverfault.com/a/696247/190386

Answer (score 0):

If your work environment imposes a network wide proxy on your computer, this can help:

```
Install-Module AzureDevOps -proxy "http://127.0.0.1:9000/localproxy-1709309785.pac"
```

substituting, of course, the URL of your local proxy. The local proxy pac URL can be viewed in the UI in Settings > Network and Internet Settings > Proxy, or you may find it with one of the answers to https://serverfault.com/q/696020/190386.   For myself, the only Powershell answer that worked was https://serverfault.com/a/696247/190386